# Displaying only the similarities between 20 or so files?

Tags: header, diff, footer, n-way-merge, n-way

Say I've got a directory full of html pages.  Their headers and footers are basically the same, but I want to be able to see only the portions of all the pages that are the same.  I'd like to call it an n-way merge, but that isn't what it is, it's looking for just the similarities between the header and the footers of all the files.

(and my header I don't mean just the <head> tag, but rather the portions of the page that are alike).

Note: There are like 20 html files.

Is there a name for a tool that does this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for what they have in common, you need a [Clone detector](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone).
Such a tool finds the common code fragments across an arbitrarily large
number of files and reports the commonality.   A good one will discover
commonality based on target langauge structure in spite of white space changes, etc.,
e.g., it isn't comparing lines but rather copy-and-pasted structures.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ExamDiff](http://download.cnet.com/ExamDiff/3000-2248_4-10059626.html)