# Term for diff/delta on multiple files or data structures

Tags: diff, terminology, conceptual

I would like to know whether there is a proper term to describe "diffing" of / obtaining the delta between multiple files or data structures, such that the resulting "diff" contains first a description of the parts common to *all* files/structures, then descriptions of how this "base" file/structure must be modified to obtain the individual ones, ideally in a hierarchical fashion if some files/structures are more similar to each other than others.

There are some questions and answers about *how* to do this with certain tools (e.g. [DIFF utility works for 2 files. How to compare more than 2 files at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1075708/2748899)), but as I want to do this for a specific type of data structure (namely JSON), I'm at a loss as to what I should even search for.

This type of problem seems to me like it should be common enough to have a name such as "hierarchical diff" (which however seems to be reserved for 2-way diffs on hierarchical data structures), "commonality finding", or something like that.

I guess a related concept about hierarchical ordering of commonalities and differences is [formal concept analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis), but this operates on sets of properties rather than hierarchical data structures and won't help me much.

Comment: What I found out so far: according to [this](http://eelco.lempsink.nl/thesis.pdf), the sub-problem at the center of this is called *Maximum Common Embedded Subtree* and defined generally for any number of trees, but most publications then limit the number of trees to 2. According to [this](https://search.ieice.org/bin/summary.php?id=e75-d_1_95), "the problem is NP-hard if the number of input trees is more than two", which perhaps explains the total lack of libraries I've found so far. [This](https://journals.openedition.org/msh/pdf/11751) describes an approximate polynomial-time algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are multiple valid denominations :**

- Data comparison (or Sequence comparison)
- Delta encoding
- Delta compression (or Differential compression)

**Algorithms:**

- [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6927) (Eugene Myer)
- [A technique for isolating differences between files](http://documents.scribd.com/docs/10ro9oowpo1h81pgh1as.pdf) (Paul Heckel)
- [The String-to-String Correction Problem with Block Moves](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1377&context=cstech) (Walter Tichy)

**Good Wikipedia links**

- [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)
- [Comparison of file comparison tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)
- [Diff Unix Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

**Some implementations**

- [diff-match-patch (Neil Fraser - Google)](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch)
- [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib)
- [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch)

Comment: Thanks, but none of these work with more than two inputs *and* compare JSON instead of files. There are some that work with more than two inputs (e.g. Diff3, although as the name suggests, it's limited to 3 inputs at most) and some that compare JSON (e.g. jsondifflib and jsondiffpatch), but none do both. Longest common subsequence problem is, I think, a special case of the maximum common embedded subtree problem I already mentioned. I guess what I'm looking for just doesn't have a handy name and isn't as common a problem as I thought it would be.

Comment: These algorithms work for 2 files but also for N files, I just looked in the [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) source code and Derrick Moser (the programmer behind the tool) use a variant of the algorithm used by [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) (longest common subsequence). And by the way Diffuse work with JSON files