# Compare more than two xml files

Tags: web-config, file-comparison

I have an IIS server with over 200 web sites.  All the sites are the same web application but for different clients.  Historically, when deploying updates we avoid updating the `Web.Config` files as some clients have "differences" to the standard version.  This is a very old web application.

Does anyone know a way to compare all these files against a single "standard" version and compile a list of which ones are different and what the differences are without having to manually compare them one at a time?

If it helps, the differences are likely, but not limited to, additional elements.  The values of elements being different would not be a problem. E.g. in the client file there was an extra `AppSettings\Add`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DIFF utility works for 2 files. How to compare more than 2 files at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time)